# Error on first line - Can't execute code in break mode

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently trying to make my life easier with an Amazon Flat File so I can input the data a lot more, yes the code is very shabby, but I'm stuck at the minute to do anything about it.

I want this program to paste in a column from a String/Int

```
Sub Lines()

Dim Brand, ClothingType, MaterialComposition, Department, StyleKeyword, TheCurrency, ProductDescription, Size, Size1, Size2, Size3, Size4, InnerOuterMat As String
Dim ItemPrice, ItemPrice2 As Double
Dim ProductSpecification, Season, CareInstructions, MaterialFabric1, Bullet1, Bullet2, Bullet3, Bullet4, Bullet5 As String
Dim ExternalTesting, Parent, Child, ParentSku, Relationship, TypeVariationTheme As String
Dim OtherImage, SaleDate1, SaleDate2 As String
Dim BrowseNode, Quantity, NumberOfItemsSalePrice, TimeToShip As Integer

    Brand = "Your Web Purchase"
    BrowseNode = "1731028031"
    ClothingType = "Shirt"
    MaterialComposition = "100%  Cotton"
    Department1 = "Apparel"
    TheCurrency = "GBP"
    StyleKeyword = "Apparel"
    ProductDescription = "Here at YWP we design a huge range of t-shirts. All of our t-shirts are created with love and the occasional cuddle to give you a unique sense of style and wit. Maybe you're a huge fan of TV, Video Games and Movies... we will have a t-shirt that's perfect"
    Size = "Small"
    Size1 = "Medium"
    Size2 = "Large"
    Size3 = "X-Large"
    Size4 = "XX-Large"
    InnerOuterMat = "Cotton"
    ItemPrice = "14.95"
    Quantity = "5000"
    ProductSpecification = "100% Cotton T-Shirt"
    Season = "Spring/Summer 14"
    CareInstructions = "Machine Washable at 40 degrees (wash inside out)"
    NumberOfItemsSalePrice = "1"
    MaterialFabric1 = "Cotton"
    Bullet1 = "Inspired By"
    Bullet2 = "Custom High Quality Exclusive Design Professionally Printedhart image)"
    Bullet3 = "100% Cotton - Soft Feel Ringspun Preshrunk Men's Tshirt (please check our size chart image)"
    Bullet4 = "Machine Washable at 40 degrees (wash inside out)"
    Bullet5 = "Check Out Our Wide Selection Of T-Shirts!"
    Child = "Child"
    Relationship = "Variation"
    OtherImage = "http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0095/3892/files/1AMAZON_MENS_Size_Chart.jpg?3145"
    ItemPrice2 = "9.69"
    SaleDate1 = "2013-07-17"
    SaleDate2 = "2050-07-18"

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Brand
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select

    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

The line where the error is showing.

```
Sub Lines()
```

Comment: it's unclear from Q what problems do you have with your current code. Also it's VB.NET or VBA?

Comment: Sub Lines()
That is the line where the error is showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Just change your Sub procedure's name:

**From**

```
Sub Lines() ... End Sub
```

**To**

```
Sub AddLines() ... End Sub
```

and it will work. The reason it's throwing the error is there's already a sub procedure/function defined with the same name -"Lines".

Comment: OH, I haven't had much experience with VBA, I was told R1C1 is a lot faster then using Value.

Comment: Also how could I go about nerfing those Variables down because there's just to many it looks so untidy.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be working, I get the same error, clicking debug navigates me to the top where "Sub Lines()" is.

Comment: Hi, thank for your help, could you explain why? Are you not aloud single words?

Comment: Oh, a sub function that is already written by VBA? One last thing if you didn't mind.

Comment: Well I want it to paste this line next to the current but if I do this

[code]
    ActiveCell.Value = Brand
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = BrowseNode
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = BrowseNode
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
[/code]

That is the way I would want to do it, offset by 1 but instead I have to do it like this

`code`
    ActiveCell.Value = BrowseNode
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = BrowseNode
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
`code`

Comment: Hi, that doesn't matter anymore, I thought I'd have to do change the offset but I can just keep it at (0, 1). Thanks for all your help anyway.

Comment: @user3472455 – best practice is to use verbs for procedures and funcitons:  `AddLines()`, `ShowLines()`, `GetSelectedLines()`. Nouns are for variables or types, e.g. `Line`, `Count`, `SelectedObject`.